# How do I add objects to an observable array backing list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections, javafx

So I have a class called mailbox, which is a collection of messages.

Example of a message, created in a "server" class:

```
Message message1 = new Message(senderRand, recipRand, subject1, today, body1);
```

Mailbox class:

```
public class Mailbox {

    public String name;
    ObservableList<String> messagelist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>(messagelist);

    public Mailbox (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int addMessage(Message message) {
      messagelist.add(message);
    }
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing, but the idea is that I have Mailbox objects like an "inbox" that is meant to used to display email Messages objects on a javafx application.  Then I need to remove a message from an "inbox" Mailbox and move it to a "trash" Mailbox.

I don't understand how to create this backing array, basically.  Should I be extending collection in the Mailbox class?  I'm not sure how to format this mailbox class so that I can add/remove Messages from a javafx app. My javafx app is just a list of mailboxes(inbox, important, trash), next to a list of messages for selected mailbox, next to a display of a selected message.

Need mailboxes to be collections of objects. Don't know how.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have here? It looks like the right idea.

Comment: No suitable method found for add(Message), Method Collection.add(String) not applicable, argument mismatch Message cannot be converted to String

Answer (score 0):

*Solution*

- You don't need a backing list for your use-case (the [`FXCollections.observableArrayList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList--) call has already created a list for you).
- You need to set the type of the list appropriately (`<Message>`, not `<String>`).

*Sample Code*

```
public class Mailbox {
    private final String name;
    private final ObservableList<Message> messages =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Mailbox (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addMessage(Message message) {
        messages.add(message);
    }

    public ObservableList<Message> messages() {
        return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(messages);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

*Implementation Note*

The above solution uses [`FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#unmodifiableObservableList-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) to create and return an unmodifiable wrapper list on top of provided observable list.

```
return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(messages);
```

If you it is OK that an external object can modify the messages list directly without interacting further with mailbox methods, then you could just write:

```
return messages;
```

If that was the case, then you probably wouldn't need the `addMessage` method call at all, because a user of the class could just write:

```
mailbox.messages().add(new Message());
```

Comment: I don't understand the line FXCollections.unmodifiableObserableList(messages); in the messages() method, is that supposed to work?

Comment: What line don't you understand?

Comment: the unmodifiableObs thing, is that method that works? Am I missing an import? What does that do, exactly.

Comment: I added an implementation note to explain the use of `unmodifableObservableList`.